# How do I count the number of occurrences of a digit in a list?

Tags: python

I have a function that gets the input of 2 numbers, n >= 0 and d > 0.

I shall square all numbers between 0 and n, then count the numbers of times d occurs in each of n^2.

Example: n = 4, d = 1

1^2, 2^2, 3^2 = 1, 4, 9, 16. Now I want to return '2' since the digit 1 which is d, occurs 2 times.

My idea was to create a new list where I append all new n-squared numbers then counting the occurrences of d in that list. count() only seems to count if it's exactly 'd' isolated from other numbers.
What should I use instead?

```
def nb_dig(n, d):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        square = i ** 2
        new_list.append(square)
    return new_list.count(d)
```

Comment: Start by asking a simpler question: how do you count the number of occurrences of a digit **in a single number written in base 10**?

Comment: You can just convert the number to a string then check if the character (aka your digit) is in that string. Example: `if str(5) in str(15):`

Comment: Naive approach: `sum(str(i).count('1') for i in new_list)`?

Comment: @Aymen What about a number like `55`?

Comment: @Axe319 good point xD they should use `count()` instead.

Comment: @Axe319: Probably a titch faster is to count a single large `str` all at once, rather than counting in each of many small strings and summing, `''.join(map(str, new_list)).count('1')`. Obviously higher peak memory consumption of course.

Answer (score 1):

You should add each element of the `square` (not `16` but `1` and `6`). You can do this by adding another `for` loop like this:

```
def nb_dig(n, d):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(n+1):
        square = i ** 2
        for g in str(square):
            new_list.append(int(g))
    return new_list.count(d)
```

And output will be `2` :) Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Converting numbers to strings in order to discover their attributes seems weird to me. This would be my preference:

```
def square_and_count(n, d):
    c = 0
    for q in [i * i for i in range(1, n+1)]:
        while q > 0:
            if q % 10 == d:
                c += 1
            q //= 10
    return c

print(square_and_count(4, 1))
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `str.join` all the numbers into one string using a comprehension then count how many times `d` appears in it:

```
def nb_dig(n, d):
    return ''.join(str(i*i) for i in range(n+1)).count(str(d))
```

---

```
>>> nb_dig(4,1)
2
```